# Chrome extension: Get last used tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a simple plugin for Google Chrome. One of the functions would be a return to the last used tab, but I don't know how to do it.

So, is there any way to get the last used tab?

Comment: if you use jquery UI tabs...every tab has its id. is this the case in your system? meaning will a tab have its unique id?

Comment: Chrome has its own API, so I can select all tabs in current window (with theirs ID, title, etc..). 

For example, I have popup window (browser action) with link to some page. After close this page (or after a few seconds) I want to select the tab from which user came.

Everything I need is algorithm or function to select (find) last used tab. 

**Update:** I found [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nikomkkhhpfoeamojhhgpfkpkdlfhfii), which can do exactly I want, but I can't find that piece of code which do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try adding a hook into the onSelected event of the tabs and just saving that variable... soemthing like this:

```
var curTabID = 0;
var curWinID = 0;

chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function(tabId, selectInfo) {
   curTabID = tabId;
   curWinID = selectInfo.windowId;
});
```

Then you have the window id and the tab id at all times.

Comment: Hmm, I checked this and function chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged returns tabID of new tab, not old.

For example I have two tabs - first(ID = 1) and second (ID = 2). If i change selection from first to second tab, I will get ID 2 not 1.

Comment: Yes exactly what is expected, onSelectChanged will tell you when it changes, at the start of this function curTabID will have the old ID and tabId the new one. If you want to keep track of all the tabs and the order they were used just use an array and push() the ids instead of setting them like I did.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** This answer does not help the questioner, but I thought it may be helpful for upcoming Firefox developers, which land here, because of Firefox now sharing the same api as chrome.

**Firefox webextension programmers** don't have to track the tab their self. They can query it like this instead, due to the lastAccessed property:

```
  chrome.tabs.query({
    active: false
  }, (tabs) => {
    let tab = tabs.reduce((previous, current) => {
      return previous.lastAccessed > current.lastAccessed ? previous : current;
    });
    // previous tab
    console.log(tab);
  });
```

**Edit**: It's worth to mention, that the lastAcessed timestamp is also set if a new tab is created in the background. So this method is not perfectly bullet proof, since the tab opened in the background will be treated as the last visited tab.

Comment: I guess this one could work only in Firefox? I couldn't see 'last accessed' param for tabs, for example, in Vivaldi

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [chrome.windows.getCurrent](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-getCurrent) function  to get the current window and [chrome.tabs.query](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) function to get the active tab in this window.

Here is an example (script from the background page):

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(
  function(win) { 
    // win is a Window object referencing the current window
    chrome.tabs.query({'windowId': win.id, 'active': true}, 
      function(tabArray) { 
        // tabArray is a Tab Array referencing active tab(s)
      }
    ); 
  }
);
```

Comment: I think event based code is better, because it runs again after each event fire. Problem is that both codes retun id of current tab. I want ID of tab from which I came to this tab.

Comment: `currentWindow: true` query filter accomplishes the same.

Answer (score 1):

For V3

```js
let lastTabID = 0
let lastWindowID = 0

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(({tabId, windowId}) => {
  lastTabID = tabId
  lastWindowID = windowId
})
```

---

[onActivated parameter](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onActivated)

> It needs an *activeInfo* which is an **object** that contains property `tabId` and `windowId`

and you can use [Object restructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) to help you  (i.e. `{tabId, windowID} = activeInfo`  )

---

V2 to V3

> [Manifest V3 required due to the use of Promises and `chrome.tabs.onActivated()`, replacing `chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#move-the-current-tab-to-the-first-position-when-clicked)